# Чтение данных полученных с вебстраницы

Tags: delphi, http

Нужно реализовать достаточно простой алгоритм. Делаеться GET запрос, после него php скрипт выводит текст, вот мне нужно программно из делфи получить этот текст и запихнуть его в переменную, как это сделать?
Допустим скрипт вывел "successfully"(Через echo допустим) я должен получить этот текст из ответа и запихнуть его в переменную.

Comment: Ну вы и ввязались на свою голову. В delphi с такими вещами всё плохо. Вам придётся писать HTTP-клиент руками.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В delphi с такими вещами всё хорошо

например можно воспользоваться TIdHTTP

например

```
Memo1.Lines.Text:=IdHTTP1.Get(Edit1.Text);
```

где в Edit1.Text пишется URL типа http://myserver.ru/?page=3

Answer (score 0):

Только, важно, выставить в True значение HandleRedirect

Comment: Для получения простотово Get-а необезательно.